# Windshield is pink although I have searched missing files

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I'm new to Blender and I know something is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it. The windshield is pink as something has happened with the texture. I looked under the nodes and this is my view. ( Already tried to find missing files ) Any help?

[image]

Comment: What color are your lights? Are any of them pink?

Answer (score 0):

The color of the whole piece looks a little pink. You might check your light tints. The windshield texture looks like it's okay as you have the window sticker in the right place.

To make the windshield look less pink, but you like the scene light color the way it is, you could color the windshield tint nodes with green to counteract the effect of the pink light.